# Text aninamtion is shaking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I was coding away on my newest project of learning css animation.

I've come a long way but for some reason when I scale my div-boks with a text element inside the text begins to shake when it appears.

What is the solution to this...
Btw I do care about effecienty as I will be rated on that for my project.
If javascipt is a better option and you know how to provide that please do
(best in the form of a tutorial page as I actually want to learn the code :D)

I will later use it to for responsive design so keep that if possible it would be nice to find a solution that cheaks that boks too

Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("topnav_id");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.scrollTop > window.innerHeight) {
      document.getElementById("topnav_id").style.top = "0px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("topnav_id").style.top = "-300px";
    }
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marck+Script&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

/* animations */

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .fa-down-long {
        position:relative;
        animation-name: hover-up-down;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
}

@keyframes hover-up-down {
    0%   {left:0px; top:30px;}
    25%  {left:0px; top:30px;}
    50%  {left:0px; top:50px;}
    100% {left:0px; top:30px;}
  }

/*  */

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .title {
        position:relative;
        animation-name: opacity-apper;
        animation-duration: 10s;
    }
}

@keyframes opacity-apper{
    0%   {opacity: 0%; transform: scale(0.5);}
    100% {opacity: 100%; transform: scale(1);}
}

* *:not(.topnav, #topnav){
    margin: 0;
}

.background {
    height: 100vh;
}

.background_header{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(/assets/placeholders/Front\ page.jpeg);
    background-position: center;   
}

.background_black{
    background-color: black;
}

h1{
    font-size: 8vw;
}

h2{
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.title {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 200px auto ;

    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    padding-top: 30vh;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* menubar */

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .flex{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      column-gap: 2rem;
    }
  }
  
  #topnav_id{
    top: -300px;
    transition: top 0.3s;
  }
  
  /* menubar responsvie */
  
  .logo{
    color: black;
    width: 300px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width:600px) {
    .topnav{
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99;
    }  
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .topnav{
      position: fixed;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99;
    }  
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
    color: black;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(.active), .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Beta1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class=" background background_header">
        <header class="header" id="header">
            <div class="topnav" id="topnav_id">
                <a href="index.html" class="active"><img class="logo" src="assets/Clean logo shite.svg" alt="Website_Logo"></a>
                <div class="flex">
                  <a href="#news">Skills</a>
                  <a href="#contact">About</a>
                  <a href="#about">Contact</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Protfolio 
                      <i class="fa fa-caret-down dropdown_icon"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="front_page.png" download="Desgin_Portfolio">Design</a>
                      <a href="#">School</a>
                      <a href="#">Public</a>
                      <a href="#">Social Media</a>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:4.2rem;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h1>I Make Visions Into Reality</h1>
                <h2>Scroll to find More!</h2>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-down-long" style="font-size: 5rem; padding-top: 4vh;"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background background_video">

    </div>

    <div class="background background_white">

    </div>
    <div class="background background_black">

    </div>
    <script src="scripts/scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/responsive.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fd59281c27.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- Colors:
-----------------------------
New Black   -       #11121a
Orange      -       #11121a
Blue        -       #5865F2
Red         -       #ED4245
-----------------------------

******************************************

Font:
-----------------------------
Title       -       Oswald
-----------------------
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
---
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');   
-----------------------------       
Fancy       -        Marck Script  
-----------------------
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
---
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Marck+Script&display=swap');
-----------------------------
Text        -       Arial
----------------------- -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations that scale or move position can cause "lag" or "stuttering", especially for low/mid end pc's. It's also recommended not to play too many animations at the same time since that can cause stuttering too. I have a portfolio website with a lot of animations which run fine on my personal pc, but can stutter on my work laptop. I'm thinking that's the issue in this case since your animation runs fine for me.

an article that might help:
https://www.keycdn.com/blog/animation-performance

Comment: You have a point here, after running a test I can see some 'minor' preformance issues with the animations. Allthought, I actually found a way to make it smoother on its own in css.

Will look into the method above as I will add more animationt to the site in the future.